# python regex only apply one replace

Tags: python, regex, file

I'm in-place editing a file using `fileinput` as below.

```
for line in fileinput.input():

    line = re.sub(pattern1, repl1, line)
    line = re.sub(pattern2, repl2, line)
    print(line, end="")
```

I want to apply `re.sub` only once for each line. If first pattern matches and replaced, I don't need to inspect pattern2.

How do I codify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use re.subn, it returns the text and the number of subs made

```
for line in fileinput.input():

    line, n = re.subn(pattern1, repl1, line)
    if not n:
        line, n = re.sub(pattern2, repl2, line)
    if not n:
        line, n = re.sub(pattern3, repl3, line)

    ...

    print(line, end="")
```

Or if you have many patterns:

```
for line in fileinput.input():

    for pattern in patterns:
        line, n = re.subn(pattern, repl1, line)

        if n:
            break

    print(line, end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.search` upfront to check if pattern1 exists and then make decision based on that:

```
for line in fileinput.input():

    if re.search(pattern1, line):
        line = re.sub(pattern1, repl1, line)
    else:
        line = re.sub(pattern2, repl2, line)

    print(line, end="")
```